# WebAudio setting gainNode.gain.value

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to deal with a deprecated Chrome feature of the WebAudio API that has to do with setting gainNode.gain.value. My current code is this:

```
var source = ctx.createBufferSource();
var my_gain = -1; //or 1, depending on whether I want sound or not
source.gainNode.gain.value = Math.min(1.0, Math.max(-1.0, gain));
```

This, however, gets me an error message: "[Deprecation] GainNode.gain.value setter smoothing is deprecated and will be removed in M64, around January 2018. Please use setTargetAtTime() instead if smoothing is needed. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5287995770929152 for more details"

To get the error message disappear, I can do something like this:

```
source.gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, ctx.currentTime, 0.015);
```

But how do I incorporate `my_gain` variable into this?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you should not bother with this message. When you read the link they do provide, they only talk about an hidden unspecified behavior they had, that they will remove. But I don't think you were expecting using this feature in your own code, but that you rather just wanted to set immediately the gainNode's value, without any ramping. And I don't believe the way you are doing is wrong in any way, but rather Chrome's message is a bit too verbose. Also, ultimately, you would use `setValueAtTime(your_value, ctx.currentTime)` to do the same.

Comment: I agree, Chrome's message is verbose. For now, if I don't do anything, the code still works. The problem is that if I were ever to use `setValueAtTime(my_value, ctx.currentTime)`, I'm not sure what to insert into `my_value`. Inserting `my_gain` from my original example above doesn't work...

Comment: `my_value` here is the result of what you set as `source.gainNode.gain.value` i.e `Math.min(1.0, Math.max(-1.0, gain))`

Comment: Hmmm, just tried to implement this, but when `my_value` is -1 (i.e., when I want the sound to be turned off), the audio is still playing at full volume. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (In other words: `var gain_value = Math.min(1.0, Math.max(-1.0, my_gain));
                        source.gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(gain_value, ctx.currentTime, 0.015);` doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you CAN just ignore this message.  Smoothing shouldn't matter much to you in this situation.  If you DID want smoothing, you should use:

```
source.gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(my_value, ctx.currentTime, 0.015);
```

The reason setting my_value to -1 isn't working is that it SHOULDN'T - all you're doing is inverting the sound (i.e., sound values are between -1 and 1 to begin with, this would flip them but not make them zero).  What you SHOULD do, in order to turn the sound off, is make my_value=0.

Comment: And if you do want to be compatible with the old behavior, the time constant of the `GainNode` was 5 ms.  So instead of 0.015, use 0.005.

Comment: Thanks, cwilso! By the way, I would like to thank you wholeheartedly for developing pitchdetect.js! It's a great library that I've found very useful for my projects!